# Why the dataReceived event does not work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem with the reception data from serial port.

In my class:

```
class Connection
{
    SerialPort Port = new SerialPort();

    public void ConfigurePort( string name, int speed)
    {
        Port.PortName = name;
        Port.BaudRate =  speed;
        Port.DataBits = 8;
        Port.Parity = Parity.None;
        Port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        Port.Encoding = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;
        Port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        Port.RtsEnable = true;

    }

   public void Write()
    {
        Port.Write("TAD->TIC,LIST");   
    }

    public void OpenPort()
    {
        try
        {
        Port.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(),"Error",  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

    }

    public void ClosePort()
    {
        try
        {
            Port.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    public static void DataReceivedHandler( object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
    }

}
```

In my Form1:

```
 private void XXX_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.ConfigurePort("COM5", 115200); 
    }


 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.OpenPort();
        port.Write();
        port.ClosePort();
    }
```

Why after click in button event DataReceivedHandler does not work?
 When the code is in the main file, everything works.

Comment: Is your event also static?

Comment: More than one problem.  Calling Write() and immediately Close() does not leave enough time to get the written data actually sent to the device.  And of course DataReceived is never going to fire on a closed port.  And if you don't set the Handshake property then you also must set the DtrEnable property to true.  And pretty unlikely that the device will know what to do with "TAD->TIC,LIST", having to use WriteLine() instead is pretty normal.  Quite a laundry list.